# Constructing matrix and vector satisfying system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, transformation, rotations

I am in difficulty with the following problem:

Let $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $u\ne v$. Constructing  matrices $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and vectors $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$
Ae_1=v-u, \quad Aa=u,
$$
$$
B(u+b)=0, \quad B(v+b)=e_1.
$$
where $e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0)\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

In my opinion this problem has a relation of rotation, transformation and dilation of coordinate system which transform $u$ into $0$ and $v$ into $e_1$ and reverse.

Thank you for all kind help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$ can simply be chosen as $A=\begin{pmatrix}v-u&u&0\end{pmatrix}$ if we let $a = e_2$

To achieve $B(u+b) = 0$ we simply pick $b = -u$ so last but not least we need to find $b$ such that $B(v-u) = e_1$, which is achieved for
$ B = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{v^Tv - u^Tu}(v^T + u^T) \\0
 \end{pmatrix}$

Note that $B$ is well-defined since we assume $v\neq u$.